# Jquery ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax

Can anybody let me know what is wrong with this code?

this function will help to remove a particular data in mysql table. Data was successfully removed but the response from the jquery ajax function is not what I expected.

```
function removeMember(id,url){
 var data = "action=removeMember&id="+id;
 var action = ajaxReturnData('POST',data,url);
 if(action == '1'){
    $(".msg").html("done");
    $("#span_delete_"+id).parent().parent().empty().hide("slow");
 }else if(action.response == '0'){
    $(".msg").html("failed");
 }
```

}

```
/*User defined functions */
function ajaxReturnData(method,data,url){
 $.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: data,
    type: method,        
    success: function(data) {
       return data;
    },
    error : function(jqXHR, exception){
        return '0';
    }
});
}
```

Comment: Yet another duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Answer (score 1):

AJAX is asynchronous. You cannot have your `success` callback return data, because it is jQuery's `$.ajax` that will be calling it, and it is not listening for a return value. AjaxReturnData will exit as soon as the request is *sent*, not when it receives a response.

You will need to pass along the callbacks (actually, you will need to rethink your logic. "AjaxReturnData" will be a weird method to have now that you know that ajax calls do not return data)

```
function removeMember(id,url){
  var data = "action=removeMember&id="+id;
  var action = ajaxReturnData('POST',data,url,function() {
     $(".msg").html("done");
     $("#span_delete_"+id).parent().parent().empty().hide("slow");      
  }, function() {
     $(".msg").html("failed");
  });
}

function ajaxReturnData(method,data,url,onSuccess,onError){
 $.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: data,
    type: method,        
    success: onSuccess,
    error : onError
 });
}
```